# Is "Snowflake Data Cloud" a good choice for a cloud-native transactional application data-store?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Currently, I generate data on a different datastore and replicate to Snowflake Staging, then that data moves to the Data Warehouse DB through ELT ingestion for Analytics purpose. However this approach can be considered as creating data-silos in itself, since we already have 3 copies of the same data:

1. Transactional data-store DB
2. Replicated snowflake staging
3. Snowflake Data Warehouse DB

From a technical architecture point of view, is it a good idea to use **Snowflake as a direct datastore** for transactional application? (application that does many CRUD operations). That may help in avoiding the cost of replication and ingestion.

The main problem I see with this approach is that: Snowflake does not enforce any referential integrity (primary keys, foreign keys) so within the CRUD app, I have to either use a MERGE statement always or somehow make sure I don't create duplicate records.

The other problem being in the cloud, the distance (aka network) between the app and snowflake decides the performance of the transactions, I want good, consistent performance of my CRUD operations.

Any thoughts/suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: *Any* remote database suffers from many small interactions due to latency, regardless of any other factors in suitability: a mere 20ms round-trip can cripple some transactional needs. This alone might make it not appropriate for OTLP/transactional workloads.

Comment: @user2864740, yes latency is still a major concern, I am weighing out the advantage of not having to replicate and ingest the transactional data separately into snowflake

Answer (score 3):

Snowflake as of today does not perform well with singleton updates and inserts, which is what we see mostly with transactional databases. I have seen a performance degradation when using singleton inserts are submitted against Snowflake.

On the contrary, they are very optimized for bulk ingestion of unstructured data and structured data though and are designed for OLAP warehouses. You can still use it but you may see the same performance degradation. Also, primary keys can be defined but they are not enforced.

In my opinion, if you are faced with that challenge, you have the option to use a Postgre SQL DB (open source) in the cloud as your transactional database and it acts as a good complement to Snowflake as the OLAP database.

Answer (score 2):

No. Snowflake isn't good as a transactional / OLTP database for the reasons you've mentioned. Plus, it won't perform well with many individual CRUD operations due to how they structure the data (optimised for OLAP workloads).

Answer (score 1):

Just want to point out that there are benefits to creating separate databases, for one you want to isolate your transactional database from that of your analytics database otherwise you could be significantly affect the performance of the application. Secondly, the data in the transactional database could change and if you had to reprocess the data for whatever reason you may not be able to do so. There are many more, but I will stop here :-)